# Print the EntityFramework Version at runtime

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Is there a way to get the version of EF at runtime? Something similar to

```
Console.WriteLine(Environment.Version);
```

will return

```
4.0.30319.18034
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extending Alexei's idea, you can do

```
string version = typeof(DbSet).Assembly.GetName().Version.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Print "version" of assembly for any type from the framework you are interested in:

```
Console.Write( typeof(String).Assembly.GetName().Version);
```